# 301 Redirect to URL with named anchor using IIS

Tags: iis, iis-6, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am trying to figure out how I can perform a 301 redirect from: http://www.examplesite.com/news to http://www.examplesite.com#news using IIS 6.0

Are there any issues associated with redirecting to a URL containing a hash that I should be aware of? Is it any different to performing a regular 301 redirect using IIS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http://www.exmplesite.com#news` is not a valid URL, so you redirect will fail.  The hash sign (#) specifies that after fetching the page, the browser should scroll to the anchor with the name specified after the hash.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Comment: Thanks for that. Much appreciated. I had seen some guides on it for Apache but wasn't sure if IIS could do the same.